# virtualization of galaxy s5 on computer

Tags: virtualization, galaxy, s5

I follow this topic :

https://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/3dkwew/how_to_get_the_samsung_s6_3_packs_and_card_back/

to get free boosters but it dont work. S5 dont load on genymotion. virtualBox show me this error :

AMD-V is being used by another hypervisor (VERR_SVM_IN_USE).
VirtualBox can't enable the AMD-V extension. Please close all other virtualization programs. (VERR_SVM_IN_USE).

error : 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Composant : 
ConsoleWrap
Interface : 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

I have tried many uninstall/reinstall but it still dont work :/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read the help documentation and follow the guidelines, especially in http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: If you are using windows it could be that hyper-v is enabled and virtual box and hyper-v cannot run together.  Some internet searches should show how to disable hyper-v.  If it is disabled then some other virtualization software is using the virtualization extensions, perhaps VMware.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the option, Configuration Settings->System->Acceleration->Virtualization HW: Enable VT-x/AMD-v.

Comment: Virtualization HW should be disable of enable ?
For now its enable